# Still getting output that I want to exclude through sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to exclude 'bQR' through the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM buyers
LEFT JOIN event ON buyers.fk_tiEvenementID=event.idEvent
WHERE buyers.tiTransactiedatum >='2018-01-01' & buyers.SaleChannelDescr != 'bQR';
```

However, the bQR still pops up.

Comment: That query is invalid in several ways. You have a table tickets condition in the WHERE clause, but you don't select from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using proper boolean syntax (rather than bit operators).  And if you intend a `left join`, move the condition on the second table into the `on` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM buyers b LEFT JOIN
     event e
     ON b.fk_tiEvenementID = e.idEvent
WHERE b.tiTransactiedatum >='2018-01-01' AND b.SaleChannelDescr <> 'bQR';
```

Your query references a table called `tickets`.  I am assuming this is really `buyers`.